# ElasticSearch: Deleting then adding a document

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a problem with making sure that my index are not corrupted. So the way I do my Add and Index actions make sure that the index is not desynchronized with my DB:

1. Get document version from index
2. Get document from DB
3. Index document

This means that it doesn't matter in what order my index requests come in my index is always in sync with DB. The problem comes with `Delete` action. There can be a situation that `Add` request comes after a `Delete` and the document is re-added even though it shouldn't be. I know that Lucene doesn't remove the document right away. Is there any way to know the ids of deleted documents? Alternatively, check the version of a deleted document? If yes how long after the delete request does the document live in the index?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might work :
1. when a document is deleted, it is not removed form the index, but is replaced by a "delete document". This can be achieved by introducing the concept of an empty document with the same ID which will replace the existing document with an empty document when it is "deleted". 
2. Before every insert, check if the document is a "delete document" and if so skip the insert/index action, if document does not exist or is not a "delete document"  then index the document.  This is basically additional work  that needs to be done  but allows for running into deletes and adds coming in out of order.

Relying on getting ids from the deleted list of docs that lucene might maintain someplace, will put  in an additional constraint of timing. Lucene/ES cleans up the deleted docs whenever it needs to.